# c# JSON Serialisation (from string)

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I am trying to serialise an object into JSON and it works partially but not everything serialises correctly.

The substitutions object is not serialising correctly unfortunately (please see below)

```
{  
   "personalizations":[  
      {  
         "to":[  
            {  
               "email":"asfasfasdfasdf@afaaaaad.de"
            }
         ],
         "substitutions":"{ \"[-button-text-]\" : \"Confirm\", \"[-button-url-]\" : \"https://localhost:44378/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=...\" }"
      }
   ],
...
}
```

I want the serialisation object to serialised to something like:

```
"substitutions": {
   "[-button-text-]" : "Confirm",
   "[-button-url-]" : "https://localhost:44378/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=..."
}
```

I am serialising my object like below:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sendGridRequestBody);
```

And the substitution attribute of the sendGridRequestBody.Personalizatoins object is set as a string with the value of:

```
"{ \"[-button-text-]\" : \"Reset Password\", \"[-button-url-]\" : \"" + callbackUrl + "\" }"
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance!
Please let me know if I need to provide further infromation!

Thanks, Nikolai

Comment: Generally speaking you can decorate your class as a `DataContract` and use the `DataMember(Name = "-button-text-")` on properties. It would probably be easier to help you out if you included your class and the desired json.

Comment: Can you also add the class that you Serialize into? Sounds like it's probably some modeling issue with your class.

Comment: I have just managed to fix it.. Rather than serialising it from a string I am now serialising from a Dictionary.